# Как правильно: Динамика повышения или просто динамика цен?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексическая-сочетаемость

Как назвать таблицу? В таблице отображены только те детали, цены на которые были увеличены...
Стоит вариант: Динамика повышения цен на детали.

Я задумался: Ведь динамика это не только повышение а общая картина(повышение и понижение)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ДИНАМИКА, -и; ж. [от греч. dýnamis - действующий] **2. Состояние чего-л., находящегося в движении, развитии, и перспективы его изменения (противоп.: статика). Д. государственного бюджета. Д. производительности труда. Д. исторических событий** (Толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова).

Как видно из толкования, само слово "динамика" не означает конкретное движение (вниз/вверх). Как вы правильно заметили, динамика - общая картина.

> **Поэтому "движение цен" не дает нам представления о именно росте цен, напротив, под "динамикой цен" можно понять как повышение, так и понижение.**

Ср.примеры из Национального корпуса.

― Из вашей статьи: «Оборот за прошлый год составил порядка 19 млн рублей. Годовая **динамика роста** ― плюс 35%. Соответственно, за 2013 год оборот ожидается в коридоре от 20 млн до 22 млн рублей». [Роман Аранин. Полтора года спустя // «Эксперт», 2015]

С учетом инфляции, которая в 2013 году составила 6, 5%, **динамика роста** доходов отрицательная. [Наталья Зубаревич. Ржавые скрепы сверхцентрализации // «Эксперт», 2014] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

В жизни **динамика нарастания** эффективности бывает и выше. [Вера Краснова. Вам не придется экономить // «Эксперт», 2014]

Что касается конкретных ставок комиссий, то **динамика на снижение** есть, это мировой тренд.

Comment: На мой взгляд говорить о *динамике роста* аналогично тому, что говорить о *скорости повышения скорости*. Последнее имеет смысл, это ускорение, но у него другие величины и его нельзя путать со скоростью. Так же надо различать динамику цен и динамику роста цен.

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы. Корректен только вариант "**динамика цен**". Чтобы не быть голословным, я проверил в Нацкорпусе: там есть "динамика цен", но нет ни одного вхождения типа "динамика повышения" или "динамика понижения".

Comment: @М-Г, динамика - этои есть движение. Не скажете же вы, что движение вверх или вниз - плеоназм.

Comment: @Серж *Движение (куда?) вверх*  аналогично *положительной динамике*, а *динамика (чего?) повышения* — это как *движение повышения* (в таком сочетании слов не вижу смысла). А по поводу *динамики роста* см. мой комментарий к Вашему ответу.

Comment: Ср.: динамика населения и динамика роста населения. Это же не одно и то же.

Comment: Честно говоря, я не понял, что вы имеете в виду, сравнивая положительную динамику с движением вверх/вниз.

Comment: "Ср.: динамика населения и динамика роста населения"  => Да это разные вещи, и что? Мы ведь говорим о ценах. *Динамика населения* не имеет аналогии в мире цен. А вот *динамика численности населения* аналогична *динамике цен*, а *динамика роста населения* аналогична *динамике роста цен*. Далее см. мои рассуждения в комментарии к Вашему вопросу, которые приводят нас к выводу, что *динамика цен* и *динамика роста цен* - разные понятия.

Comment: "Честно говоря, я не понял, что вы имеете в виду, сравнивая положительную динамику с движением вверх/вниз." => Честно говоря, я уже потерял нить спора. Какой тезис мы обсуждаем. То, что движение вверх или вниз - не плеоназм? С этим я согласен. А далее что?

Comment: Если ***динамика населения и динамика роста населения*** - это разные вещи, тогда в чем вы видите проблему? Получается, вы признаете корректность этой фразы?

Comment: @Серж, Корректность какой фразы?

Comment: динамика населения и динамика роста населения

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68664/discussion-between---and-).